# How can I transfer Minecraft pe from my iPhone to my MacBook Pro?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to play Minecraft pe on my computer tho I don't know if there is any way I can transfer the game from my iPhone to my MacBook Pro... I could use some help, please.

I don’t need to transfer the worlds, just the game.

Comment: Are you trying to transfer your *worlds*, or the *game* to your computer?

Comment: The game, not the world**.

Answer (score 1):

Wait nevermind it seems you want to transfer the *game*? If you mean you want an executable iPhone is pretty locked down you cannot achieve that.
I think that also would be illegal even if you could because you would be distributing Minecraft assets and the entire game code itself.